# cakephp - neighbor records with tag type

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have three database tables, `news`, `news_n_types`, and `n_types`.

The `n_types` table is filled with the different types of news tags.

The `news_n_types` table maps `n_types` to `news`.

A news posting can belong to many different news types. I'm trying to find the neighbors of a news post with a particular new type.

So far if I try the following everything works but it searches for any news post and not just ones in that type.

```
$this->News->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('NewsNType')));
        $neig = $this->News->find('neighbors', array(
            'fields' => array('News.*')
        ));
```

If I add a condition to filter the news type I recieve a sql error (SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'NewsNType.n_type_id' in 'where clause')

```
$this->News->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('NewsNType')));
        $neig = $this->News->find('neighbors', array(
            'fields' => array('News.*'),
            'conditions' => array('NewsNType.n_type_id' => $typeID)
        ));
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update per request**

After looking at the data returned from the first query, it too may not be working, as it never returns a previous.

app/controllers/news_controller.php (line 102)

```
Array
(
[prev] => 
[next] => Array
    (
        [News] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [title] => TEST 1
                [date] => 1319935806
                [body] => TEST 1
                [excerpt] => TEST 1
            )

        [NType] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [label] => Blog
                        [slug] => blog
                        [NewsNType] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 25
                                [news_id] => 1
                                [n_type_id] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [label] => Industry News
                        [slug] => industry_news
                        [NewsNType] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 26
                                [news_id] => 1
                                [n_type_id] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Can you post an example of the data returned by the first query?

Comment: @David Gallagher I added more info

Comment: As next has the id 1 I wouldn't expect that there is a prev. What I would be more concerned about is the fact that there is no NewsNType in your next.

Comment: Updated results after switching recursive to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I found it not possible to use conditions on another table when using `find('neighbors')` this way. You need to do a join:

```
$joins = array(
    array('table' => 'news_n_types',
        'alias' => 'NewsNType',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'NewsNType.news_id = News.id',
        )
    )
);
$conditions = array('NewsNType.n_type_id' => $typeID);
$neig = $this->News->find('neighbors', array('field' => 'id', 'value' => 1, 'joins' => $joins, 'conditions' => $conditions));
```

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation

> [find('neighbors')] does not honor a model’s default recursive var. The
>   recursive setting must be passed in the parameters on each call.

Try using:

```
$neig = $this->News->find('neighbors', array(
        'fields' => array('News.*'),
        'conditions' => array('NewsNType.n_type_id' => $typeID),
        'recursive' => 1
    ));
```

Comment: I updated my first post with the results after setting recursive to 1.